# Как посчитать колличество каждой из цифр в массиве JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня есть массив:

```
[5, 2, 8, 1, 7, 3, 1, 5, 10, 5, 11, 7, 1]
```

Как в нем посчитать количество каждой из цифр?

Например тут три пятерки и только одна десятка.

Если делать циклами то их получиться очень много.

Может не очень понятно, я хочу получить:

```
5 - 3   
2 - 1
8 - 1
и т.д.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это достаточно просто сделать при помощи [структуры данных Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

Создаем карту и запускаем цикл [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) по массиву из цифр, на каждой итерации вызываем метод [set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) по нашей карте. Он задает значение для ключа, которым является текущий перебираемый элемент.

Что бы вычислить новое значение мы спрашивает есть ли уже такой ключ в нашей карте и если да то берем существующее значение и прибавляем к нему единицу, а если нет то определяем как один.

```
const countNumbers = numbers => {
    const map = new Map()

    for (const number of numbers) {
        map.set(number, map.has(number) ? map.get(number) + 1 : 1)
    }
    return map
}

const result = countNumbers([5, 2, 8, 1, 7, 3, 1, 5, 10, 5, 11, 7, 1])

console.log(result)

// Map {
//   5 => 3,
//   2 => 1,
//   8 => 1,
//   1 => 3,
//   7 => 2,
//   3 => 1,
//   10 => 1,
//   11 => 1
// }
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Answer (score 0):

Вроде не сильно много циклов:

```
numbers = [5, 2, 8, 1, 7, 3, 1, 5, 10, 5, 11, 7, 1];
numbers_select = [5,2,8]
output = {}
for(int l = 0; l < numbers.select.length; l++) output[l] = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers_select.length; j++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] == numbers_select[j])
        {
            output[numbers_select[j]]++;
        }
    }
}

console.log(output);
```