# Как узнать можно ли разделить массив на массивы последовательно повторяющихся чисел JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Мне помогли разобраться c тем [как узнать количество каждого из значений в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160900/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-javascript), но я так и не могу понять как сделать так что бы узнать смогу ли я разделить массив на суб-масивы по количеству повторяющихся элементов.

Массив приходит:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

и если `условие равно 4`, то я это массив могу разделить, так как мне хватает повторяющихся чисел:

```
[ [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6] ]
```

если `условие равно 2` то так же могу, а `если 3` то уже нет.

Как это можно проверить?

Comment: Вы получаете массив и вот это самое значение (например 4) и на выходе Вам нужно только понимать можно ли его разделить или нет?

Comment: @Vasily да на выходе только результат

Comment: `return arr.length % n == 0` ? о_О а как должно выглядеть разделение по 2 ? Не понятно, что значит "субмассивы по количеству повторов"

Comment: могу разделить на четыре потому что повторяться тройка и четверка, разделение на два тоже можно что видно если разделить пример с 4 еще раз, они будут по два и идти последовательно. по три никак так как уже и цифр повторных нехватает для последовательного по 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]

const checkArray = (numbers, n) => {
  if (!numbers.length % n) {
    return false
  }

  const map = new Map()

  for (const number of numbers) {
    map.set(number, map.has(number) ? map.get(number) + 1 : 1)
  }

  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (map.get(number) === 0) {
      continue
    }

    while (map.get(--number) > 0);

    ++number

    const count = map.get(number)

    for (let index = 1; index < n; ++index) {
      const current = map.get(number + index)
      if (current === undefined || current < count) {
        return false
      }

      map.set(number + index, current - count)
    }

    map.set(number, 0)
  }

  return true
}

console.log(checkArray(array, 4)) // true

console.log(checkArray(array, 2)) // true

console.log(checkArray(array, 3)) // false
```

Comment: Спасибо! нужно было сразу спрашивать целиком, но думал что сам смогу допереть

Comment: Кажется, вопрос и ответ понятны только вам и автору) `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6]` разделение по 3 дает false... а можно же `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 6], [4, 5, 6]]`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME там в комментарии было написано что последовательных чисел. У Вас второй массив в этом случае должен был бы заканчиваться цифрой 5, поэтому false